# Autoloading module level classes and config files in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I am trying to auto-load classes from the "lib" directory inside of one specific module directory.

I have tried everything but to no avail... 
One of the classes I would like to load is a class called visUser which inherits from myUser I have already made a factory.yml file in myapplication/modules/mymodule/conf but it doesn't load...

I am doing something wrong? or module level configuration files are not suported?

I am using symfony 1.2 with propel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factories are an application specific file and cannot be overloaded on the module level. It's a weird idea anyway.

Read the config handlers file to see what files are supported on the modules level configuration (symfony/lib/config/config/config_handlers.yml).

Comment: Ok, I will read it, I thought that I was able to overwrite every configuration file at any level, it seems that I was wrong...

Thank you very much!